# How can I remove a marker after a certain amount of time and even if the app is closed?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Currently I am working in an Android studio app using google maps and markers. 
The idea for this app is that the user can only be allowed to put one marker every one hour so if the users adds a marker to the map after one hour the marker should disappear. 
The thing is that I want that marker to stay in the map within that hour even if the user closes the app. I am having problems with this as the marker stays for ever in the map if I close it. S how can I resolve this? Does postDelayed stops when I close the app? Am I using runnable and handler in the correct way?

This is my code:

```
public void drawMarker(View view) {
        if (marker == null) {
            Location loc = returnLocation();
            Double lat = loc.getLatitude();
            Double lon = loc.getLongitude();
            //para guardar un marker en sharedPreferences
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Lat",String.valueOf(lat)).apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Lng",String.valueOf(lon)).apply();
            marker = addMarker(loc);
            dialogPlayas.dismiss();
            removeMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            markerHandler = new Handler();
            markerHandler.postDelayed(timeRemoveMarker, 10000); //van a durar ua hora osea 3600000 milisegundos
        }
    }

    private Runnable timeRemoveMarker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            marker.remove();
            removeMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("Lat").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("Lng").apply();
            marker = null;
        }
    };


    public void removeMarkerButton(View view) {
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("Lat").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("Lng").apply();
            removeMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //markerHandler.removeCallbacks(timeRemoveMarker);
        }
        marker = null;
    }
```

This is the code I use to make the marker appear when I restart the app:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        goToLocation();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("LatLng",MODE_PRIVATE);
        //Check whether your preferences contains any values then we get those values
       if((sharedPreferences.contains("Lat")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("Lng")))
        {
            Location loc = new Location("");
            String lat = sharedPreferences.getString("Lat","");
            String lng = sharedPreferences.getString("Lng","");
            LatLng position =new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));
            Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lng);
            loc.setLatitude(latitude);
            loc.setLongitude(longitude);
            addMarker(loc);
            removeMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new windowInfo(MapsActivity.this));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas to resolve this?
I also think that if the user removes a marker the handler should stop running so I was doing something like this

```
public void removeMarkerButton(View view) {
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("Lat").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("Lng").apply();
            removeMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            markerHandler.removeCallbacks(timeRemoveMarker);
        }
        marker = null;
    }
```

But whenever I add a marrker and restart the app, touching the remove button makes my app stop working. Thats because of the removeCallbacks but I dont know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

in `drawMarker(View view)` method, add this line:

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
```

Then in your `onMapReady` when the app is restarted add this:

```
Long then = sharedPreferences.getLong("time",0);
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (now - then > 3600000) { // 3600000 == 1 hour
    // not adding the marker
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the coment. I will try this.